# Creating a random GDAL raster with random predefined values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, random

So far I have developed the below code but for some reason it only works for say one class of land-use instead of two. Would you please tell me where I have gone wrong?

```python
import os, numpy, osgeo.gdal, math, random, sys
from osgeo.gdal import *
import  osgeo.gdalconst, osgeo.ogr
osgeo.gdal.AllRegister()
driver = osgeo.gdal.GetDriverByName('RST')
driver.Register()
ds = osgeo.gdal.Open('landii.rst')
cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize
ds.GetProjection()
print 'no of cols is:', cols
print 'no of rows is:', rows
print 'Raster has %s bands' % ds.RasterCount
geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()

out = driver.Create ('chandal.rst', cols, rows, 1, osgeo.gdal.GDT_Byte)
driver = ds.GetGeoTransform
raster = numpy.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=numpy.int32)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        coll = 0
        raster[i][j] = coll
out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)              
perc = [0.65, 0.45] # perc is the percentage of the pixels to be allocated to land use 1 and two respectively

nclasses = 2
for ii in range(nclasses):
    l = perc[ii]
number = int(cols * rows * l)
while (number > 0):
    rand1 = random.randrange(rows)
    rand2 = random.randrange(cols)
    k = raster[rand1][rand2]
    if k == 0:
        raster[rand1][rand2] = ii 
        number = number - 1

out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)       

out = None
```

Comment: you have all the spaces. Is this just because something went wrong copying it in here or is this actually your code. Maybe you could updated it, before we start working on the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the spaces here are mistakes,

Comment: Maybe you could update the code without the spaces, this way it would be easier to work with it.

Comment: please forget about the lines spaces

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet to get a weighted choice is to use [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) which allows you to specify the sample set, and a weight for each sample. Note the probability must sum to exactly 1.

```python
raster = numpy.random.choice([0, 1], size=(rows, cols), p=[0.65, 0.35])
```

Also, a quick note: your comment says the probability that the landuse should be allocated to 1 or 2, but your data type is a binary raster which can only ever have the values of 0 or 1. Instead you should use an integer type if you want to keep the values 1 and 2; `gdal.GDT_Int32`

Also, if you're looking at expanding on your code above a couple of code issues:

- There is no need to pre-set the zero raster values to zero - it's already done when the array is initialised with `numpy.zeros`.
- With a consistent input raster the value of `number` will always be the same - effectively `cols * rows * 0.45`. The loop over the `perc` finishes before you assign the value to `number`.
- You can index a 2D numpy array with `raster[row, col]`
- Finally rather than using GDAL directly I'd take a look at the [`rasterio`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) library which is a much more pythonic wrapper around GDAL.